# Intel X540-T1 10GigE NIC works, but extremely slow, high latency on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, intel, 10gbethernet

I have a new Intel X540-T1 network adapter. I installed the latest ixgbe-4.1.5 driver from Intel. The card is able to get an IP address from DHCP. However, viewing websites and installing packages with `apt-get` are extremely slow, and BitTorrent just doesn't connect. For example, I downloaded Webmin with apt-get to see if it could be of help. It took a few tries before apt-get was finally able to resolve the domain names, then it took a few minutes to download ~20 megs. However, normally a download like that would take a minute or so (I'm connected to a fast university LAN connection).

Any thoughts? Might some parameters for the ixgbe module help, and if so, which?

I did search around. This question doesn't apply to my situation: [intel-nic-x540-t1-non-functional-in-ubuntu-server-12-04](https://serverfault.com/questions/447136/intel-nic-x540-t1-non-functional-in-ubuntu-server-12-04).

Note: there isn't an IP associated with the 10GigE adapter at the time of the output below, or else I wouldn't be able to be on this site.

Some outputs:

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.13.0-66-generic #108-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 7 15:20:27 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ ifconfig p1p1
p1p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:36:9f:75:5c:ca  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

$ ethtool -i p1p1
driver: ixgbe
version: 3.15.1-k
firmware-version: 0x8000037c
bus-info: 0000:01:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no

$ sudo lspci -vvnns 01:00.0
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2 [8086:1528] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet Converged Network Adapter X540-T1 [8086:0002]
    Physical Slot: 2
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 26
    Region 0: Memory at f2200000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Region 4: Memory at f2400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Expansion ROM at fb100000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
    Capabilities: [70] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=64 Masked-
        Vector table: BAR=4 offset=00000000
        PBA: BAR=4 offset=00002000
    Capabilities: [a0] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 512 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable+ Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+ FLReset-
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <1us, L1 <8us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Device Serial Number a0-36-9f-ff-ff-75-5c-ca
    Capabilities: [150 v1] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
        ARICap: MFVC- ACS-, Next Function: 0
        ARICtl: MFVC- ACS-, Function Group: 0
    Capabilities: [160 v1] Single Root I/O Virtualization (SR-IOV)
        IOVCap: Migration-, Interrupt Message Number: 000
        IOVCtl: Enable- Migration- Interrupt- MSE- ARIHierarchy+
        IOVSta: Migration-
        Initial VFs: 64, Total VFs: 64, Number of VFs: 0, Function Dependency Link: 00
        VF offset: 128, stride: 2, Device ID: 1515
        Supported Page Size: 00000553, System Page Size: 00000001
        Region 0: Memory at 00000000fb280000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable)
        Region 3: Memory at 00000000fb180000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable)
        VF Migration: offset: 00000000, BIR: 0
    Capabilities: [1d0 v1] Access Control Services
        ACSCap: SrcValid- TransBlk- ReqRedir- CmpltRedir- UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
        ACSCtl: SrcValid- TransBlk- ReqRedir- CmpltRedir- UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
    Kernel driver in use: ixgbe

$ lsmod | grep ixg
ixgbe                 233377  0 
dca                    15130  2 igb,ixgbe
ptp                    18933  2 igb,ixgbe
mdio                   13807  1 ixgbe

$ modinfo ixgbe
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-66-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ixgbe/ixgbe.ko
version:        4.1.5
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) 10 Gigabit PCI Express Network Driver
author:         Intel Corporation, <linux.nics@intel.com>
srcversion:     9781CEF8A3110F93FF9DBA8
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015ADsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001560sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001558sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000154Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001557sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000154Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000154Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001528sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000151Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001529sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000152Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001514sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001507sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010FBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001517sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010FCsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F7sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001508sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010DBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010E1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010ECsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010DDsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000150Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C7sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010B6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        ptp,dca,vxlan
vermagic:       3.13.0-66-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           InterruptType:Change Interrupt Mode (0=Legacy, 1=MSI, 2=MSI-X), default IntMode (deprecated) (array of int)
parm:           IntMode:Change Interrupt Mode (0=Legacy, 1=MSI, 2=MSI-X), default 2 (array of int)
parm:           MQ:Disable or enable Multiple Queues, default 1 (array of int)
parm:           DCA:Disable or enable Direct Cache Access, 0=disabled, 1=descriptor only, 2=descriptor and data (array of int)
parm:           RSS:Number of Receive-Side Scaling Descriptor Queues, default 0=number of cpus (array of int)
parm:           VMDQ:Number of Virtual Machine Device Queues: 0/1 = disable, 2-16 enable (default=8) (array of int)
parm:           max_vfs:Number of Virtual Functions: 0 = disable (default), 1-63 = enable this many VFs (array of int)
parm:           VEPA:VEPA Bridge Mode: 0 = VEB (default), 1 = VEPA (array of int)
parm:           InterruptThrottleRate:Maximum interrupts per second, per vector, (0,1,956-488281), default 1 (array of int)
parm:           LLIPort:Low Latency Interrupt TCP Port (0-65535) (array of int)
parm:           LLIPush:Low Latency Interrupt on TCP Push flag (0,1) (array of int)
parm:           LLISize:Low Latency Interrupt on Packet Size (0-1500) (array of int)
parm:           LLIEType:Low Latency Interrupt Ethernet Protocol Type (array of int)
parm:           LLIVLANP:Low Latency Interrupt on VLAN priority threshold (array of int)
parm:           FdirPballoc:Flow Director packet buffer allocation level:
            1 = 8k hash filters or 2k perfect filters
            2 = 16k hash filters or 4k perfect filters
            3 = 32k hash filters or 8k perfect filters (array of int)
parm:           AtrSampleRate:Software ATR Tx packet sample rate (array of int)
parm:           FCoE:Disable or enable FCoE Offload, default 1 (array of int)
parm:           LRO:Large Receive Offload (0,1), default 1 = on (array of int)
parm:           allow_unsupported_sfp:Allow unsupported and untested SFP+ modules on 82599 based adapters, default 0 = Disable (array of int)
parm:           dmac_watchdog:DMA coalescing watchdog in microseconds (0,41-10000), default 0 = off (array of int)
parm:           vxlan_rx:VXLAN receive checksum offload (0,1), default 1 = Enable (array of int)
```

Answer (score 1):

shot in the dark and this question is rather old, but do you have ip forwarding enabled (yes?) or are you using this in conjunction with bridging tools (do not appear to be)? Try disabling LRO.

From the intel release notes:

### Important Notes

### Disable LRO if enabling ip forwarding or bridging

WARNING: The ixgbe driver supports the Large Receive Offload (LRO) feature. This option offers the lowest CPU utilization for receives but is completely incompatible with *routing/ip forwarding* and *bridging*. If enabling ip forwarding or bridging is a requirement, it is necessary to disable LRO using compile time options as noted in the LRO section later in this document. The result of not disabling LRO when combined with ip forwarding or bridging can be low throughput or even a kernel panic.